# Rescuing errors in Rails 3.2 with `config.exceptions_app = self.routes`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

As per this post:

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/

The newest way to handle errors looks like this:

```
# application.rb:
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

#routes.rb
match "/404", to: "site#not_found"
```

However, he doesn't address the fact that the rails error app also handles 500 errors, 422 errors (and possibly other errors funneled to those two pages?)

So I've hacked together a solution that looks like this:

```
# routes.rb
rack_error_handler = ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions.new('public/')
match "/422" => rack_error_handler
match "/500" => rack_error_handler
```

It's good in that it keeps my 500 pages lightweight.

Are there other errors I should be catching as well?
My understanding is that although the 500 page will now be using two rack apps, it is still safely isolated from the main Rails App enough.  Is this strong?

Thanks!

Comment: For rails 4:  http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/custom-error-pages-with-rails-4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add the rescue froms in the application controller

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate, :with => :render_not_found
  end

  def render_not_found(exception)
    logger.info("render_not_found: #{exception.inspect}")
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'The page was not found.'
  end
```

and then add a errors_controller to rescue the route errors adding this to the bottom of my routes file

```
  match "*path", :to => "errors#routing_error"
```

Comment: note that the `rescue_from` block accepts an array of arguments, simplifying this further: http://code-worrier.com/blog/error-pages-in-rails/

Comment: the match all route at the end seems too hackish to me.. no offense but any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Update `config/application.rb`

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

and your route file

```
match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"
```